# What does the 20-80A rating on an energy meter mean?

Tags: energy, electricity, power-consumption, meter

On the energy meter nameplate is a current rating 20-80A, which I can assume has something to do with max current.
I'm particularly interested in the "20" part, though. What does this rating mean? I don't want to assume that this 20 is the minimum current that the meter can measure because it really wouldn't make sense to me. Internet articles aren't really clear on this, so I'm hoping I can get clarity on the matter.

Comment: Please add make and model and a link to the datasheet into your question so we can read the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifications of the meter only apply on the range between 20A and 80A. Below or above it is less accurate.

Which makes, sense. If you put your multimeter in 600V mode, you're not on the scale to confidently measure 6V.